# how to Create NFS Stale file handle

Tags: linux

I would like to Re-Create the "NFS Stale File handle error" in linux manually. I read a similar Question and Solution in this site but the solution didn't work for me.

Please suggest if there are easy ways to recreate this error using commands/tools etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: It is related to removing (unlinking) some file on the client.